# Python (Pywin32) Referencing Own Cell/Horizontal Movement

Tags: python, excel, com, pywin32, vba

So please don't tell me to google or research or read anything, I've been doing that for the past couple of days and will get annoyed if I see someone say that again.

My problem: I am using pywin32 and python 2.7.8 to communicate with (an already existing) excel sheet. I use it to log my hours worked and money earned, etc. I have it functioning to the point that I can open the workbook, find the next empty cell under my existing entries and write the date in that cell. My problem lies in the fact that I need to navigate horizontally. I want the program to run automatically so I will not always know the number of the cell. For example, my current cell is 18,1. I need to move to 18,2 18,3 18,4 and 18,5. But next time I run the script I may need 19,2... etc.

How can I do this? Is there a way to return the current cell or something?
code:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import os, time

xl = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.visible = True
xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.join('C:\\Users\\[REDACTED]\\Desktop', '[REDACTED].xls'))
xlSheet = xl.Sheets(1)
activecell = xlSheet.Cells(1,1)

def GetEmptyCell():
    global activecell
    activecell = xlSheet.Cells(1,1)
    for c in range(1,99,1):
        if activecell.Value == None:
            print 'Empty cell'
            activecell = xlSheet.Cells(c,1)
            print '(' + str(c) + ',1)'
            return activecell
        elif activecell.Value != None:
            c += 1
            activecell = xlSheet.Cells(c,1)
            print 'Full cell, next'

GetEmptyCell()

def WriteToEmpty():
    global activecell
    global HoursWorked
    global GrossIncome
    global NetIncome
    HoursWorked = raw_input('Input amount of hours worked: ')
    GrossIncome = float(HoursWorked) * 9.15
    NetIncome = float(GrossIncome) * 0.86233
    print 'Money Made: ' + str(GrossIncome) + ' Take Home: ' + str(NetIncome)
    activecell.Value = time.strftime('%a') + ' ' + time.strftime('%m') + '/' + time.strftime('%d')
    #HELP FROM HERE

WriteToEmpty()``
```

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens of ways to acheive what you want. If you have contiguous data in column A you could use something like xl.range("A1").end(xldown).offset(1,0).address to get the address of the first cell in the next empty row.  Or you could use xl.range("A1").currentregion and offset from there.
Personally i'd probably just put the current region into an array and work from there, then dump the array back to the sheet, but thats always my preference, most people seem to prefer to work on the sheet.